# Parsing ENV with SED

Tags: sed, environment-variables

I have an env file

```
ENV=development
PORT=3000
SECRET_KEY=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nKEYKEYKEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

How can I parse this file using SED to properly format it?

Used this solution

```
for line in `cat ${FILE_NAME_ENV}`
do
  KEY=$(echo $line | sed 's/=.*//')
  VAL=$(echo $line | sed 's/[^=]*=//')
  echo $KEY
  echo $VAL
done
```

But SECRET_KEY is splitting over multiple lines due to spaces in the value

```
ENV
development
PORT
3000
SECRET_KEY
-----BEGIN
PRIVATE
PRIVATE
KEY-----\nKEYKEYKEY\n-----END
KEY-----\nKEYKEYKEY\n-----END
PRIVATE
PRIVATE
KEY-----\n
KEY-----\n
```

How can i make key value in one line?

```
SECRET_KEY
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nKEYKEYKEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -n 's/^\(SECRET_KEY\)=/\1\n/p' input_file
SECRET_KEY
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nKEYKEYKEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

Comment: How to make it in a loop if SECRET_KEY can be any other name? Take any key before = and print values after = even with spaces

Comment: So just `s/^\([^=]*\)=/`

Comment: @KamilCuk please full string

Comment: @AlexK. `sed -n 's/^\([^=]*\)=/\1\n/p' input_file`

Comment: @HatLess for some reason, the output to the file is duplicated and the key is still new line  https://pasteboard.co/qM0Yp9mp3qwV.png

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to enclose `echo` command arguments with `"` to contain each line as single argument to command.

#### Suggestion 1: fix missing `"`

```
for line in "$(cat ${FILE_NAME_ENV})"; do
  KEY=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/=.*//')
  VAL=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/[^=]*=//')
  echo "$KEY"
  echo "$VAL"
done
```

#### Output 1:

```
ENV
PORT
SECRET_KEY
development
3000
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nKEYKEYKEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

#### Suggestion 2: fix with `echo -e` to accept `\n` as newline

```
for line in "$(cat ${FILE_NAME_ENV})"; do
  KEY=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/=.*//')
  VAL=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/[^=]*=//')
  echo "$KEY"
  echo -e "$VAL"
done
```

#### Output 2:

```
ENV
PORT
SECRET_KEY
development
3000
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
KEYKEYKEY
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: checked your solution, it doesn't work like that

Comment: in both cases there is a newline after -----BEGIN, then PRIVATE, etc.